# An adjective for incertitude

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, software, software-bugs

Context: Without the tool X, writing programs in Java is a hard and time-consuming task with lots of incertitude.

Here the *incertitude* means that programmers are not sure if their programs are correct, well-written, optimal, etc. They ask themselves lots of questions when developing; developers don't have certitude (I would like to stress the feeling of the developers).

Now, I'm looking for an adjustive to say

> Without the tool X, writing programs in Java is a hard, time-consuming, and ???? task.

Candidates may be *doubtful*, *uncertain*, *unsure*, etc.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Not incertitude. Uncertainty. Thankless task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjective "uncertain" fits exactly here. It is the natural adjective from "incertitude" (or rather from the much clearer and better-understood synonym "uncertainty").

"Uncertain" is frequently used to describe tasks, routes, and methods and means "not well defined" or "not clearly understood".

Answer (score -1):

Not a single word, but I'd go for [hit-or-miss](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit-or-miss) (also hit or miss), described by Merriam-Webster as "marked by a lack of care, forethought, system, or plan". It gives a similar sense of something that's dependent on luck, trial and error, or guessing.

Two of their example sentences are "Buying veggie burgers can be hit or miss—increase your odds of success by making your own!" and "The perch fishing around the Lake Erie Island area has been hit or miss, with fishermen reporting a dozen perch being an average catch this week."

Comment: Also *chancy*. . .

Comment: But hit-or-miss sounds like the developers don't care. Actually, developers do care, but due to the lack of tool support, they still have lots of doubt when developing.

Comment: Really not a natural adjective of incertitude, plus it is a very trite and unerudite word.